# How to add popup window in Google maps when a marker is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, google-maps

I am trying to build a dynamic Google map using jQuery JSON and PHP, some how I managed to complete the map listing using the following code example:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        // Root path to data directory
        var dataRoot = 'gmap-master/';

        // data file with markers (could also be a PHP file for dynamic markers)
        var newDate = new Date;
        var markerFile = dataRoot + 'ammap.php';

        // set default map properties
        var defaultLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.00, 10.00);

        // zoom level of the map        
        var defaultZoom = 2;
        var ndefaultZoom = 2;

        // variable for map
        var map;

        // variable for marker info window
        var infowindow;

        // List with all marker to check if exist
        var markerList = {};

        // set error handler for jQuery AJAX requests
        $.ajaxSetup({"error": function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + ' / ' + errorThrown + ' / ' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }});

        // option for google map object
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: defaultZoom,
            center: defaultLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };


        /**
         * Load Map
         */
        function loadMap() {

            console.log('loadMap');

            // create new map make sure a DIV with id myMap exist on page
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), myOptions);

            // create new info window for marker detail pop-up
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            // load markers
            loadMarkers();
        }


        /**
         * Load markers via ajax request from server
         */
        function loadMarkers() {

            // load marker jSon data        
            $.getJSON(markerFile, function(data) {

                // loop all the markers
                $.each(data.markers, function(i, item) {

                    // add marker to map
                    loadMarker(item);

                });
            });
        }

        /**
         * Load marker to map
         */
        function loadMarker(markerData) 
        {

            // get date
            var mDate = new Date(markerData['created'] * 1000);

            // create new marker location
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markerData['lat'], markerData['long']);

            // create new marker                
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                id: markerData['id'],
                map: map,
                title: markerData['creator'] + ' - ' + markerData['name'],
                position: myLatlng
            });

            // add marker to list used later to get content and additional marker information
            markerList[marker.id] = marker;


             var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">"'.markerData['name'].'"</h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
  'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
  'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
  'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
  '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
  'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
  'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
  'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
  'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
  'Heritage Site.</p>'+
  '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
  'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
  '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:contentString
            });


            // add event listener when marker is clicked
            // currently the marker data contain a dataurl field this can of course be done different
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                // show marker when clicked
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                map.setZoom(6);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

            });

            // add event when marker window is closed to reset map location
            google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {

            });

             // add marker to list
            var listItem = $("<li/>");
            $("<a/>").attr('href', '#').click(function() {
                showMarker(marker.id);
                return false;
            }).text(markerData['name']).appendTo(listItem);

            $('#myMapList').prepend(listItem);
        }


        /**
         * Show marker info window
         */
        function showMarker(markerId) {

            // get marker information from marker list
            var marker = markerList[markerId];

            // check if marker was found
            if (marker) {

                // get marker detail information from server
                $.get(dataRoot + 'data/' + 'markernew' + '.html', function(data) {
                    // show marker window
                    infowindow.setContent(data);
                     map.setZoom(6);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            } else {
                alert('Error marker not found: ' + markerId);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Adds new marker to list
         */
        function newMarker() {

            // get new city name
            var markerAddress = $('#newMarker').val();

            if (markerAddress == "") {
                $('#newMarker').addClass('error');
                $('#newMarker').attr('placeholder', 'missing location');
                return false;
            }


            // create new geocoder for dynamic map lookup
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({'address': markerAddress}, function(results, status) {

                // check response status
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    // set new maker id via timestamp
                    var newDate = new Date;
                    var markerId = newDate.getTime();

                    // get name of creator
                    var markerCreator = prompt("Please enter your name", "");

                    // create new marker data object
                    var markerData = {
                        'id': markerId,
                        'lat': results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                        'long': results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                        'creator': markerCreator,
                        'name': markerAddress,
                    };


                    // save new marker request to server
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: dataRoot + "data.php",
                        data: {
                            marker: markerData
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false,
                        success: function(result) {
                            // add marker to map
                            loadMarker(result);

                            // show marker detail
                            showMarker(result['id']);

                            $('#newMarker').removeClass('error');

                            // Track Piwik Goal
                            _paq.push(['trackGoal', 2]);
                        }
                    });

                } else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    alert("Marker not found:" + status);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

When a user clicks the marker it will invoke the function `showMarker(markerid)` but it is using HTML to load data. What I want is to set the HTML code manually in the script and when user clicks the marker a popup should be shown.

Comment: `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', {FUNCTION})`, put it in a loop if multiple `markers` are being generated to add the listener to all of them. Inside the function you can call whatever you want, you said popup window so I'm not sure if you wanted a infobox or actually a custom window. If you want a infobox you could try this: https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

Comment: hi i have added a html data in the popup window but when a user click the marker it showing error...Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: it showing error when it is embedded inside the html tag